# How to perform a Hohmann-like transfer to mercury on GMAT

Tags: orbital-mechanics, simulation, astrodynamics, hohmann-transfer, gmat

I am trying to simulate a Hohmann-like transfer from Earth to Mercury and establish an orbit there on GMAT.

I have the following values already:

- launch velocity (22.25 km/s)
- Launch burn (-7.53 km/s)
- Transfer SMA (0.694 AU)
- Transfer ECC (0.991)
- Transfer orbit length (1.03 AU)
- Transfer Time (65 days)
- Arrival velocity/ burn (616 km/s  /  -179.4 km/s)

Tutorials on Inter-planetary transfers (inward) on GMAT don't seem to exist, and the only interplanetary transfers I can find make use of B-plane coordinates. coordinates of which seemingly don't exist online for mercury nor do I have any idea how to calculate them. I am aware they would make my life a whole lot easier but hey-ho.

I have also run into a problem where there is no gravity profile on GMAT that can be applied to Mercury.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Also, if anyone can point me in the direction of B- plane coordinates of Mercury that would be fantastic.

Comment: Great question, *welcome to the site!* I've just asked in meta [What's the difference between the astrodynamics and orbital-mechanics tags? Do we need both? Will question authors always know which to use?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2872/12102)